# Dynamically Loaded Anchors Not Working On Page Load

Tags: jquery

I am generating anchors dynamically for each `<h3>` on page load, but when linking to another page the anchor doesn't scroll to the destination.  I am pretty sure this is because the anchors don't exist yet.  How can I either look at the URL and trigger the scroll after the page is ready or generate the anchors sooner?

jQuery:

```
//Add anchors with name for each h3 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('h3').each(function() {
    let text = $(this).text();
    $(this).before("<a name='" + text + "'></a>");
  });
});
```

URL structure: `https://sample.com/page/#anchor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did. In case anyone else finds it helpful.

```
//Add anchors with name for each h3 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('h3').each(function() {
    let text = $(this).text();
    $(this).before("<a name='" + text + "'></a>");
  });

  let anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");

  $('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(".content [name='" + anchor + "']").offset().top - 32
  }, 1000);  
});
```